# LEDs flash instead of staying on/off when there are multiple LEDs/buttons?

Tags: arduino

I have an issue in a sketch with 12 LEDs and 4 buttons where holding buttons are supposed to turn certain LEDs off. I made a more basic sketch with one LED and one button to show my issue, but this basic sketch worked perfectly! So I'm wondering why my basic example (sketch 1) works perfectly but the LEDs flash in my more complex example (sketch 2), please?

---

SKETCH 1 (works perfectly):

```
//sets up button and LED connections:
const int led_1 = 4;
const int but_1 = 8;

//sets up variable butState that will be changed later
int butState;

void setup() {
  //sets pin modes:
  pinMode(led_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(but_1, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  //variable that reads the button state:
  butState = digitalRead(but_1);

  //if the button state is high, sets LED state low. Opposite if button state is low:
  if (butState == HIGH) {
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(led_1, LOW);
  }
  else {
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(led_1, HIGH);
  }
}
```

---

SKETCH 2 (LEDs blink):

```
//turns all lights on. turns in1 lights off when button 1 pressed.
//turns in2 lights off when second button is pressed.
//turns out lights off when third button is pressed
//turns all lights off when fourth button pressed

//result (output) lights:
const int res_8 = A5;
const int res_4 = A4;
const int res_2 = A3;
const int res_0 = A2;

//in1 lights:
const int in1_4 = 4;
const int in1_2 = 3;
const int in1_0 = 2;

//in2 lights:
const int in2_4 = 7;
const int in2_2 = 6;
const int in2_0 = 5;

//input buttons:
const int b_4 = 8;
const int b_2 = 9;
const int b_0 = 10;
const int b_enter = 11;

// set up switch states
int b4State = 0;
int b2State = 0;
int b0State = 0;
int benterState = 0;

 void setup() {
  // set up pins
  pinMode(res_8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(res_4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(res_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(res_0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1_4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1_0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2_4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2_0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b_4, INPUT);
  pinMode(b_2, INPUT);
  pinMode(b_0, INPUT);
  pinMode(b_enter, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  //reads the state of button inputs
  b4State = digitalRead(b_4);
  b2State = digitalRead(b_2);
  b0State = digitalRead(b_0);
  benterState = digitalRead(b_enter);
  //checks button 1
  if (b4State == HIGH) {
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(in1_4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in1_2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in1_0, LOW);
  }
  else {
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(in1_4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in1_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in1_0, HIGH);
  }

  //checks button 2
  if (b2State == HIGH) {
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(in2_4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2_2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2_0, LOW);
  }
  else {
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(in2_4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2_0, HIGH); 
  }

  //checks button 3
  if (b0State == HIGH) {
    delay(1000);
    analogWrite(res_8, 0);
    analogWrite(res_4, 0);
    analogWrite(res_2, 0);
    analogWrite(res_0, 0);
  }
  else {
  delay(1000);
  analogWrite(res_8, 1023);
  analogWrite(res_4, 1023);
  analogWrite(res_2, 1023);
  analogWrite(res_0, 1023);
  }

  //checks enter button
  if (benterState == HIGH) {
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(in1_4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in1_2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in1_0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2_4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2_2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2_0, LOW);
    analogWrite(res_8, 0);
    analogWrite(res_4, 0);
    analogWrite(res_2, 0);
    analogWrite(res_0, 0);
  }
  else {
  delay(1000);
  analogWrite(res_8, 1023);
  analogWrite(res_4, 1023);
  analogWrite(res_2, 1023);
  analogWrite(res_0, 1023);
  digitalWrite(in1_4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in1_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in1_0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2_4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2_2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2_0, HIGH);
  }

//  //delays
//  delay(250);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your test.

```
  //checks button 1
  if (b4State == HIGH) {
    // turn LEDs on for 1 second
  }
  else {
    /* turn LEDs off 1 sec */         // button 4 released -> LEDs OFF, 
    /* even if button 2 is pushed! */ // even when button 2 is pushed
  }

  //checks button 2
  if (b2State == HIGH) 
  {
     // turn LEDs on 1 second
  }
  else 
  {
     // turn LEDs off 1 sec - 
     // even when button 4 is pushed!
  }
```

The logic that you want :

```
  //checks button 1
  if (b4State == HIGH)  
  {
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(in1_4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in1_2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in1_0, LOW);
  }
  else if (b2State == HIGH)            // button 4 is not pushed... check button 2
  {
    delay(1000);                      
    digitalWrite(in2_4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2_2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2_0, LOW);
  }
  else 
  {
    delay(1000);                       // only turn off the LED when both buttons
    digitalWrite(in2_4, HIGH);         // are released
    digitalWrite(in2_2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in2_0, HIGH); 
  }
```

Pressing button 2 and 4 produce the same effect in the code you posted, so the test could be reduced to a simple if / else, but I think you are  probably planning to add more code to your app.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! And yeah, the 2nd and 3rd buttons did the same thing, I was going to fix that but I wanted to fix one problem at a time. Plus, this was only a sketch to check I'd wired my board up correctly before writing the sketch that I actually want.